# Unused classes cannot be resolved in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse

I am using Eclipse Java EE IDE for Web Developers.

Version: Helios Service Release 2
Build id: 20110218-0911

Currently I am writing a bookstore project, however when compiling ShoppingCart.java, it shows

"- The type java.util.function.Consumer cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class 
     files

```
- The type java.util.function.Consumer cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class 
 files

- The type java.util.function.Predicate cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files

- The type java.util.function.UnaryOperator cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from 
 required .class files

- The type java.util.Comparator cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files"
```

at the beginning. 
This is Book.java

```
package bookstore;

import java.io.Serializable;

public class Book implements Serializable {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
private String isbn;
private String author;
private String title;
private double price;
private int edition;
private String publisher;
private String copyright;
public Book(String isbn, String author, String title, double price, int edition, String publisher, String copyright) {
    this.isbn = isbn;
    this.author = author;
    this.title = title;
    this.price = price;
    this.edition = edition;
    this.publisher = publisher;
    this.copyright = copyright;
}
public String getIsbn() {
    return isbn;
}
public String getAuthor() {
    return author;
}
public int getEdition() {
    return edition;
}
public String getPublisher() {
    return publisher;
}
public String getCopyright() {
    return copyright;
}
public String getTitle() {
    return title;
}
public void setTitle(String title) {
    this.title = title;
}
public double getPrice() {
    return price;
}
public void setPrice(double price) {
    this.price = price;
}
}
```

And ShoppingCart.java

```
package bookstore;
import java.util.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;


public class ShoppingCart extends ArrayList<Book> {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
public ShoppingCart() {
}

public void addBook(Book book) {
    this.add(book);
}

public Book getBook(int i) {
    return this.get(i);
}

public double getTotalPrice() {
    double price = 0.0;
    for (Book book : this) {
        price += book.getPrice();
    }
    return price;
}
}
```

I did not include functions of Consumer, Predicate, UnaryOperator and Comparator. I found that the problem may be due to the "extends ArrayList"

Answer (score 0):

This is an annoying Eclipse Bug which seems to bite now and then. See http://dev-answers.blogspot.de/2009/06/eclipse-build-errors-javalangobject.html

for a possible solution, otherwise try the following;

Close the project and reopen it.
Clean the project (It will rebuild the buildpath hence reconfiguring with the JDK libraries)

OR

Delete and Re-import the project and if necessary do the above steps again.